# Maven Release Plugin looking for settings file in wrong directory

Tags: maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm exploring using the maven-release-plugin with one of my projects. The issue is `release:prepare` fails with the error `The specified global settings file does not exist: F:\f\.m2\repository`

Some time ago, I moved the .m2 folder out of my user directory to free up disk space and thought I had that all cleared up. A maven package works just fine.

I'm using maven 3.8.4 and maven release plugin 3.0.0-M7

In the mvn command I specified the path using `--settings` flag pointing to the proper directory
`$ mvn --settings /F/.m2/settings.xml release:prepare`

then here is the output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.goodyear:event-data >-----------------------
[INFO] Building event-data 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M7:prepare (default-cli) @ event-data ---
[INFO] starting prepare goal, composed of 17 phases: check-poms, scm-check-modifications, check-dependency-snapshots, create-backup-poms, map-release-versions, input-variables, map-development-versions, rewrite-poms-for-release, generate-release-poms, run-preparation-goals, scm-commit-release, scm-tag, rewrite-poms-for-development, remove-release-poms, run-completion-goals, scm-commit-development, end-release
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'run-preparation-goals'
[INFO] 10/17 prepare:run-preparation-goals
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[INFO] [ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[INFO] [ERROR] The specified global settings file does not exist: F:\f\.m2\repository
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.732 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-16T08:21:55-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M7:prepare (default-cli) on project event-data: Maven execution failed, exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I've searched every file, and env variable, I can think of looking for this incorrect path, but can't find it anywhere.

Where would maven be looking to obtain that path?

Comment: Why do you need to specify the `settings.xml` location manually?

Comment: I may not have been clear, my apologies. I do not want to specify the settings file manually, I need to know where the maven release plugin could possibly be getting the incorrect path `F:\f\.m2\repository`

Comment: Have you tried to omit the settings configuration? Are you on CygWin environment or on plain windows?

Comment: yes. I've tried it both ways and the same error results. I am running this from a git bash terminal

Comment: If you have not specified the options for the settings.xml what was the exact error output?

Comment: The error is clearly delineated in the output above, `[INFO] [ERROR] The specified global settings file does not exist: F:\f\.m2\repository`. The global path, `F:\f\.m2\repository` is wrong. It should simply be `F:\.m2`. I need to figure out where the release plugin is getting the invalid path from. All other maven commands work as expected

Comment: The users settings file location is defined by default to be in the users home directory instead of a root directory. The location of the global settings file is by default within conf directory of the maven installation....